# .plaso to elasticsearch using psort.py: authentication error

Tags: elastic-stack

I have been trying to load .plaso file to elk engine using psort.py. But i am getting the Authentication Error. 
Error:
elasticsearch.exceptions.AuthenticationException: TransportError(401, u'')

also I have disabled xpath security 
Other info:

```
2017-02-25 17:28:27,720 [INFO] (MainProcess) PID:13544 <elastic> Server address:
 127.0.0.1
2017-02-25 17:28:27,727 [INFO] (MainProcess) PID:13544 <elastic> Server port: 92
00
2017-02-25 17:28:27,732 [INFO] (MainProcess) PID:13544 <elastic> Index name: c8b
d7007962e40ae8bc2360da5661706
2017-02-25 17:28:27,737 [INFO] (MainProcess) PID:13544 <elastic> Document type:
plaso_event
2017-02-25 17:28:27,743 [INFO] (MainProcess) PID:13544 <elastic> Flush interval:
 1000
2017-02-25 17:28:27,747 [INFO] (MainProcess) PID:13544 <elastic> Add non analyze
d string fields: False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\psort.py", line 880, in <module>
    if not Main():
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\psort.py", line 866, in Main
    tool.ProcessStorage()
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\psort.py", line 810, in ProcessStorage
```

Thanks for the help